# SMS sending jar not working from terminal

Tags: java, netbeans, sms

I am able to send SMS from Netbeans with my java class but when I am trying to run from terminal / command it is not working. No error is thrown. I already tried compiling in different java versions. I am working in ubuntu 14 and jdk 7 / 1.8 is used.

```
String authkey = "abc";
String mobiles = mobile;
mobiles = Arrays.stream(mobiles.split(",")) .distinct() .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
String senderId = sid;
String message = msg;
String route="4"; //Transaction
URLConnection myURLConnection=null;
URL myURL=null;
BufferedReader reader=null;
String encoded_message=message.trim();
String mainUrl="example.com/api/sendhttp.php?";
StringBuilder sbPostData= new StringBuilder(mainUrl);
sbPostData.append("authkey=").append(authkey); 
sbPostData.append("&mobiles=").append(mobiles);
sbPostData.append("&message=").append(encoded_message);
sbPostData.append("&route=").append(route);
sbPostData.append("&sender=").append(senderId);

 mainUrl = sbPostData.toString();
 try
 {
//prepare connection
myURL = new URL(mainUrl);
myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.connect();
reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
//reading response 
String response;
while ((response = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //print response
    System.out.println(response);
}

//finally close connection
reader.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) 
 { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Could not send SMS"+e);                     
  }
```

Comment: It might be an issue of permissions (what if you run it with elevated permissions, just to see what happens?) and ports. It could be that the OS 'trusts' Netbeans but not your console application. EDIT: Also ditch this: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Could not send SMS"+e);  ` and replace it with a `System.out...` just in case.

Comment: what is the command used? and console output ?

Comment: java -jar "Sms.jar" 1234567890 SENDER TEST

Comment: NO output no error

Comment: One last thing you could do would be add print statements in the program to provide an output of what is happening, a progress report if you will. This will help you identify if the program is hanging or where it is stopping.